# Why is chart being squeezed into one box when there is plenty of space in SVG?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a slope graph but it's being squeezed into one tiny box despite having plenty of SVG space.

Following the normal process, I created a larger canvas that holds all the elements of graph (including labels and axes etc) and then using margins, created a smaller canvas that holds ONLY the graph (no axes but incl some labels).

Then using a linear scale, I added the lines expecting it to take up all the space inside the larger canvas minus the margins.

However, instead the graph is being squeezed into a much smaller box and I cannot tell why. It's causing all the labels to overlap each other. Also, it looks awful because one of the axes is falling exactly where it should, which means it's really far away from graph.
[image]

I have tried changing various aspects of the code including expanding the `range()` of the linear scale but it causes only the smallest change (i.e. the lines expand a little away from each other) which is even more confusing.

I also tried commenting out all the code that moves labels around to prevent them from overlapping in case that was causing the unexpected results. But that wasn't the problem.

Clearly, something else is causing the `y` values to be confined to a smaller space than is apparent. I did copy this code from somewhere else so maybe I missed something when I modified it for my own use: https://gist.github.com/mwburke/9873c09ac6c21d6ac9153e54892cf5ec

My own code:

```
// Calculate area chart takes up out of entire svg
  let chartHeight = opts.height - opts.margin.top - opts.margin.bottom;
  let chartWidth = opts.width - opts.margin.left - opts.margin.right;

  let svg = d3
    .select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", opts.width)
    .attr("height", opts.height);

  // Create scale for positioning data correctly in chart
  let vertScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    // .range([opts.margin.bottom, chartHeight]);
    .range([0, 500]);

  // First, calculate the right and left side chart placements
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    updatedData[i]["AfterY"] = vertScale(updatedData[i]["Last"]);
    updatedData[i]["BeforeY"] = vertScale(updatedData[i]["First"]);
  }

//A bunch of other code...

// Create slopegraph labels
  svg
    .selectAll("text.labels")
    .data(updatedData)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.District;
    })
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "label " + d.Change;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("x", opts.margin.left * 0.6)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return opts.margin.top + chartHeight - d.BeforeY;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em");
```

And this is the whole code block: https://github.com/SabahatPK/Data4Pakistan_SlopeGraphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistaken assumption that my dataset values ranged from 0-100 (because it was a percentage column) but actually all the values were actually between 40-75. Once I adjusted domain to be .domain([40, 75]), the lines spread out as expected.

Now I have to make other decisions about whether graph is misleading without 0% value on the axes. But this issue can be closed out.